# Python script in windows commandline behaving way too slow?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, cmd, word-frequency

i wrote a python-class which calculates unigram-frequencies from a text using a simple function:

```
for listIndex in range(len(words)):
                    uniGramDict[words[listIndex]] =  float(float(words.count(words[listIndex])) / float(len(words)))
```

I tested the script in **windows commandline** for a corpus with 6 tokens and achieved the desired results:

```
{'a': 0.4, 'c': 0.2, 'b': 0.2, 'd': 0.2}
```

Now I run this script on a larger corpus with ~750000 tokens in windows commandline and it seems that it takes a way too large amount of time, I am waiting for 40+ minutes now.

When I look at the CPU/Memory usage of cmd.exe in the task manager, I see that almost no ressources are used: 0.0% cpu, 1.349K ram.

When I look at the CPU/Memory usage of python.exe *32 in the task manager, I see that not much ressources are used: 25% cpu (i guess one of 4 cores) and 43.544K ram.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the task? Is `import multithreading` and its proper use what I am looking for?

Thank you,

b.

Comment: if you want efficiency for this kind of tasks I would recommend to use `CountVectorizer` from `scikit-learn`. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage

Comment: Despite the multithreading your code could be easily improved: You call `float` three times where *once* is sufficient. Also you go through your whole text several times, where one time would be enough. For every `word`  for find increase a counter `uniGramDict[word]` by one. You can then filter your dict for the words you are interested in.

Comment: @RobinKoch i tried to use `float(words.count(words[listIndex]) / (len(words)))` instead of `float(float(words.count(words[listIndex])) / float(len(words)))` but that left me with frequencies = 0

Comment: @bngschmd You cast after the division. Try: `float(words.count(words[listIndex])) / len(words)` That way you divide `float/integer` which results in float division.

Comment: I just notice that your word list and your token are the same list! That means that you call `count()` 50000 times, even if words appear multiple times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multithreading to speed up the process. Just a better algorithm.
In your code in - order to count every word - you make 50000 * 50000 = 2,500,000,000 comparisons! And you count words everytime you see it again. (Imagine your corpus is 50000 the word "foo". So you count 50000 time the word "foo", keeping only the last result an discarding the other 49999.)

That's quadratic growth. For twice as many tokens you need 4 times as long.

Instead go through your list *once* and count every word that you see on your way:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def goodcount(words):
    wordcount = defaultdict(int)
    for word in words:
        wordcount[word] += 1
    return {word:float(wordcount[word])/len(words) for word in wordcount}
```

You can do it with standard dictionaries as well as with `defaultdict`, but then you have to initialize every entry first:

```py
def goodcount2(words):
    wordcount = dict()
    for word in words:
        if wordcount.has_key(word):
            wordcount[word] += 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] = 1
    return {word:float(wordcount[word])/len(words) for word in wordcount}
```

Let's compare:

```py
tokens: 50000

yourcount:  69.432s
goodcount:   0.016s
goodcount2:  0.031s
```

Not sure why you were waiting for 20 minutes, but 70 seconds for a 16µs job is a little too much already.

**Edit:**

I see you now use 750,000 tokens. That's 15 times as many as before (50,000). So Your code should take 225 times as long as before!

On my machine that would be around 4h 22min.
The linear approach should need approx. 15*0.016s = 0.24 s

Comment: well im not sure why i was waiting 20 minutes neither. any idea would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would do.

```
from __future__ import division
for listIndex in xrange(len(words)):
    try:
        uniGramDict[words[listIndex]] += 1
    except:
        uniGramDict[words[listIndex]] = 1
```

The reason I used `xrange` is because it is a lot faster than `range`
and the reason I used the `__future__` import because it didn't take you the `float` function at all and because the `/` now represents true division, not floor division.
NOTE:  The `__future__` import should be at the first line of the program